# How to set pandas dataframe column as index when generating loading matrix for PCA

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pca, genetics

I am using sklearn in python to perform principle component analysis (PCA) on gene expression data. My data is loaded as a pandas dataframe, for which I can call df.head() and the df looks good. I am using sklearn to generate a loading matrix, but the matrix only displays a generic index, and will not accept a column name for an index. I have 1722 genes, so it is important that I obtain the loading score for each gene computationally.

Here is my code for PCA:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn import preprocessing


# Load the data as pandas dataframe
cols = ['gene', 'FC_TSWV', 'FC_WFT', 'FC_TSWV_WFT']
df = pd.read_csv('./PCA.txt', names = cols, header = None, index_col = 'gene')

# preprocess data:

scaled_df = preprocessing.scale(df.T)


# perform PCA

pca = PCA()
pca.fit(scaled_df)
pca_data = pca.transform(scaled_df)


# Generate loading matrix. HERE IS WHERE THE TROUBLE IS:

loading_scores = pd.Series(pca.components_[0], index = df.gene)


# Print loading matrix

sorted_loading_scores = loading_scores.abs().sort_values(ascending=False)
print(loading_scores)
```

I have tried:

```
loading_scores = pd.Series(pca.components_[0], index = df.gene)

loading_scores = pd.Series(pca.components_[0], index = df['gene'])

loading_scores = pd.Series(pca.components_[0], index = df.loc['gene']
```

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'gene'.

If I do not specify an index at all, the loading scores are designated with the generic 0-based index.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `df.index` instead of `df.gene` or `df['gene']`

Once you set a certain column to be the index, the way to access it is through the `.index` attribute, and not through the column's name anymore.

Comment: Didn't work. new error message reads: "     ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis    "